# Unable to call class method in the constructor of a Dart class

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am new to Dart programming. Need help in updating the List "items" before instantiating the super class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import '../util/color_constants.dart';

class CustomBottomNavigatorBar extends BottomNavigationBar{

  final List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items;

  CustomBottomNavigatorBar(
      this.items,   ): super(backgroundColor: ColorConstants.facebook_blue,items: updateListWithDefaultIcons(items));

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> updateListWithDefaultIcons(){
    items.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(
      label: 'Settings',
      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
      tooltip: 'Settings',
      backgroundColor: ColorConstants.white,));
    items.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(
      label: 'Profile',
      icon: Icon(Icons.man),
      tooltip: 'Profile',
      backgroundColor: ColorConstants.white,));
    return items;   } }
```

Here is the error that Dart throws up while compiling the code

```
The instance member 'updateListWithDefaultIcons' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable instead of method `updateListWithDefaultIcons` and pass default on items. and it is recommended not to create `items` variable that is coming from parent.

```dart
class CustomBottomNavigatorBar extends BottomNavigationBar {
  final List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items_;

  CustomBottomNavigatorBar({
    Key? key,
    this.items_ = _updateListWithDefaultIcons,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
          items: items_,
        );

  static const List<BottomNavigationBarItem> 
                    _updateListWithDefaultIcons = [
                         BottomNavigationBarItem(...)
                         .... ]
}
```